# Persistent Hash Table Implementation

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, hashtable, persistent

In a program I'm working on, I develop a large "thread tree" (at most k children per node), where each thread makes some modifications to a hash table inherited from its parent. Is there a way to implement a hash table that is somewhat "persistent" (in the sense of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) ?

Namely, is there a way to implement a key-value pairing with at least O(log n) lookup, insertion, and deletion that is fully persistent, but is as "space-efficient" (worst-case) as an ordinary hash-table?

Comment: In that wikipedia article there are atleast 5 different kinds of persistent, what kind of persistence are you looking for?

Comment: Full persistence, just updated the original post

Comment: If I understood your problem well, if you want each child, to inherit the hash table from his parent, you could just make a deep copy of the hash table everytime a child is created/added.

Comment: @Muggen: that's an O(n) operation for every childbirth. A persistent data structure takes this down to O(1) at the expense of O(lg n) for the lookup, insert and delete operations.

Comment: Are you in Java, or C++?

Answer (score 5):

"As space-efficient as an ordinary hash-table" is a rather vague specification, since "ordinary" may mean linked or probed depending on who you ask. I don't think anyone has designed easy-to-understand persistent hash tables yet.

The easiest way to get a persistent key-value map with the complexity that you want is to use a persistent binary search tree. Lookup is the familiar algorithm from ephemeral (non-persistent) BSTs. Insert changes however, and becomes something like (pseudo-Java):

```
// overwrites the value for k if it's already in the tree
Node insert(Node node, Key k, Value v)
{
    if (k < node.key)
        return new Node(node.key, node.val, insert(node.left, k, v), node.right);
    else if (k > node.key)
        return new Node(node.key, node.val, node.left, insert(node.right, k, v));
    else
        return new Node(k, v, node.left, node.right);
}
```

Note that the insert routine returns a new tree, which may seem inefficient, but it only changes those nodes it traverses. This is on average O(lg *n*), so it does O(lg *n*) allocations on average. This is about as space-efficient as it gets.

To get worst-case O(lg *n*) behavior, use a red-black tree. See also the literature on data structures in functional programming, e.g. the works of Okasaki.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Okasaki's work; if you can track down a copy of his book on purely functional data structures you'll have access to all sorts of fun solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to implement a key-value pairing with at least O(log n) lookup, insertion, and deletion that is fully persistent, but is as "space-efficient" (worst-case) as an ordinary hash-table?

Indeed there is. Many ways.

E.g. in Haskell, the simple [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Map.html), a *size balanced* binary trees (or trees of bounded balance) as described by:

- Stephen Adams, "Efficient sets: a balancing act", Journal of Functional Programming 3(4):553-562, October 1993, http://www.swiss.ai.mit.edu/~adams/BB/.
- J. Nievergelt and E.M. Reingold, "Binary search trees of bounded balance", SIAM journal of computing 2(1), March 1973.

Provides the following API, satisfying your criteria:

```
insert :: Ord k => k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a   -- O(log n)
lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a        -- O(log n)
delete :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Map k a        -- O(log n)
```

while being fully-persistant. Space use is *O(n)*.

For better constant factors, try e.g. a [`Data.HashMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hashmap/1.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-HashMap.html) data structures, with the same overall complexity.

Alternative structures include:

- persistent tries, which have improved space use over hashtables, as key storage is dense.

Comment: Since insert and delete work using path copying, I thought each insert can cost Omega(lg n) space, so that maintaining k versions can cost Omega(n + k lg n) space.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure has implemented a whole set of persistent data structures, such as hash maps. It's open source, so maybe you should take a look?

http://clojure.org/data_structures

http://code.google.com/p/clojure/source/browse/trunk/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java

Answer (score 1):

> Namely, is there a way to implement a key-value pairing with at least O(log n) lookup, insertion, and deletion that is fully persistent, but is as "space-efficient" (worst-case) as an ordinary hash-table?

Yes. Section 5 of Driscoll et al.'s ["Making Data Structures Persistent"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/Persistence.htm) shows a technique for making fully persistent red-black trees with O(lg n) time and O(1) space complexity for insertion, deletion, and lookup.

Their data structure is not confluently persistent. For more on persistence, see [Kaplan's survey on the topic](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~haimk/papers/persistent-survey.ps).

Comment: This paper is fine for theoretical considerations, but is there some actual C code out there that implements persistent red black trees?  Seems like all the libraries I find (e.g. GNU libavl) are *not* persistent, and understanding red black trees is hard enough without tacking on persistence...

Comment: Use Google with the keywords: persistent red-black driscoll